# ActionBarCompat - showAsAction="always|withText" not working

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using ActionBarCompat and have an options menu defined in XML. It looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/createNew"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:title="@string/createNew" />
</menu>
```

The icon appears in the actionbar, but without text! How can I get the text showing? What did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What else do you have in your action bar (tabs? list nav? custom view?)? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Is there any other elements present actionbar.One more thing to tell use of "always" is not good practice. Always use "ifroom".

Comment: Yes, I know that ifRoom is better, but it doesn't work either. There's nothing in my ActionBar, just the defaults: an icon, title, and the button I mentioned. There's a huge amount of room on the left of it! However when I rotate the device to landscape orientation, it displays correctly.

Comment: I've also tried to use both "android:" and "app:" namespace prefix for showAsAction parameter, but it's still displayed without text :( Any idea?

Comment: @ÁronLőrincz, did you find the solution ?. I am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: Unortunately, I didn't. But prefer the new Toolbar instead of the obsolete ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine here. I have tested it, the only problem might be the device screen size.

Try to test it on landscape mode or big screen device.

Comment: Well, actually the problem is that there IS enough room for it. Even, it displays without text!